# How do I Map one array value agaisnt another to produce a result

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Let's say there are two arrays

Array 1 is my Firebase JSON array of Objects as follows:

```
"players" : [
       {"name" : "YB", 
        "Team" : "Industry",
        "id": 1, 
        "position": "forward",
       {"name" : "Harry",
        "Team" : "Industry", 
        "id": 2, 
        "position": "defender",
        {"name" : "Honey",
        "Team" : "Industry", 
        "id": 3, 
        "position": "defender",
        {"name" : "abel",
        "Team" : "Industry", 
        "id": 4, 
        "position": "defender",
        {"name" : "Shaka",
        "Team" : "Industry", 
        "id": 5, 
        "position": "defender",
        {"name" : "ben",
        "Team" : "Industry", 
        "id": 6, 
        "position": "defender",
        {"name" : "randy",
        "Team" : "Industry", 
        "id": 7, 
        "position": "defender",
        {"name" : "john",
        "Team" : "Industry", 
        "id":8 , 
        "position": "defender"
         }
       ]
```

Array 2 is

```
[1,2,5,4,8,6]
```

Is there a way to loop through `array 1`, specifically the object property `id` , in search of the values of `array 2` and then producing a resulting array of only the objects that have the ids `1,2,5,4,8,6` (i.e. an array of only the objects that have the `id` property value that corresponds with the values in `array 2`)

I'm very new to javascript/firebase cloud functions and was wondering how to achieve that. I tried a mapping function below:

```
var produce = array1.reduce (function(acc,next) {acc [next.id] = next; retrun acc;}, {});

var combine = array1.map(function(num){return produce[num];});
```

But it keeps returning an error message that a`rray1.map is not a function`. There has to be a simpler way to achieve this goal using the map `function.`

Comment: Your json is not valid `"id": ,`

Comment: Error is telling you that `array1` is not an array. The array is probably `array1.players` depending on how you defined `array1`

Answer (score 2):

You can use filter your records by using `.filter()` and checking `id` in second array using `.includes()`:

```js
let data = [
  {"name" : "YB",    "Team" : "Industry", "id": 1, "position": "forward"},
  {"name" : "Harry", "Team" : "Industry", "id": 2, "position": "defender"},
  {"name" : "Honey", "Team" : "Industry", "id": 3, "position": "defender"},
  {"name" : "abel",  "Team" : "Industry", "id": 4, "position": "defender"},
  {"name" : "Shaka", "Team" : "Industry", "id": 5, "position": "defender"},
  {"name" : "ben",   "Team" : "Industry", "id": 6, "position": "defender"},
  {"name" : "randy", "Team" : "Industry", "id": 7, "position": "defender"},
  {"name" : "john",  "Team" : "Industry", "id": 8, "position": "defender"}
];

let matchIds = [1, 2, 5, 4, 8, 6];

let result = data.filter(({ id }) => matchIds.includes(id));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

From the error it could be deduced that the variable you are trying to map is not an array. 
Let's assume that the firebase response is of the following format:

```
var result = {"players":[
                           {"name" : "YB","Team" : "Industry", 
                            "id":1,"position":"forward"},
                           {"name" : "Harry","Team" : "Industry", 
                            "id": 2,"position": "defender"}
                          ]
              }
```

And, let the second array be as follows:

```
  var array2 = [1,2,5,4,8,6];
```

So the "result" variable is actually an object here and not an array. In this case, we might try something like the following to prevent the error mentioned in the question from occuring:

```
var finalResult = result.players.filter (function(player) {
                  return array2.indexOf(player.id) > -1;
              });
```

Comment: this returns the TypeError : array2.indexOf is not a function.

Comment: @DejiJames , I have made the correction in the answer to obtain proper output, but that type error should not occur if you have defined array2 as an array.